# How can I save my game of Zork that i am playing in DOSBox?

Tags: zork

I am playing Zork on a Snow Leopard Mac, using DOSBox. I type in save but it says to save to this path c:save\zork1.dat. I am not sure what to do, also it says to insert a save disk so I don't if I should put in a cd or something else.

Comment: A CD? You seem to be too young to remember [floppy disks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_disk).

Comment: i remember them, but just not that well. i used them only about 5 times.

Comment: There's a lot of ways to play Zork on a Mac. If you have the original DAT file as you seem to you could download Zoom or Spatterlight. I believe there are websites that allow you to play as well. They save files to the filesystem using menu commands or in-game (as in SAVE).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just save the game normally. Don't put in a disk or anything.

The game will be saved to your mount point for the C: drive.  For example, If your mount point is `/Users/Foo/Documents/Zork/`, then the game will save to the `./save/` directory in the `./Zork/` folder.

When you want to resume playing, load up Zork then type `restore` at the prompt and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  It should point to your existing save file.  If not, type where your save is located, for example, `C:\Save\zork1.dat`, then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: OK, BUT HOW DO I RESTORE IT WHEN I WANT TO PLAY AGAIN?

Comment: @codegeek511 Added to my answer.

Comment: Just built Zork I from source at https://github.com/devshane/zork and running it. Got into house and needed to save.  Thanks very much!